# Actionscript 3.0 depthing changes effect my 2.0 depth management

Tags: actionscript-3, depth

I'm finally taking the time to go from Actionscript 2.0 to Actionscript 3.0, and I'm trying to figure out how to pull off a simple depthing system I had at my disposal in 2 that doesn't seem to be possible in 3.
The code goes something like this:

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    this.swapDepths(1000+Math.ceil(this._y));
}
```

This way, I could easily get mock 3D effects as something moves up and down on the screen.
Also understand, this is a really basic application of the idea. Usually I'd put in logic to allow multiple movieclips to exist at one Y value.
Whatever the case, with the changes to AS's depthing, this method is no longer possible in this state.  Maybe I just have an incomplete knowledge of how the new system works, I am just a hobbyist AS programmer, but is there a better/simpler/more elegant way to pull this off in AS3.0, short of keeping track of *every* clip/sprite on the stage?

I'm using Adobe Flash CS4 professional, if that makes any difference.  Additionally, this isn't of much importance, yet.  I'm still getting my bearings, but I came across the depthing changes during a quick project a few weeks ago when learning about adding Child MovieClips, and it seemed like I could only *easily* add things to the front or back of the stage, not inbetween.

Comment: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/03/29/understanding-howas3-manages-depths/

Comment: If you're wondering what I'm trying to accomplish, think Battletoads or Double Dragon.  _That_ kind of depthing, where it's supposed to be entirely reliant on the objects' y coordinates.  Additionally, if this is just a much more complicated affair than it used to be in AS2.0, I'm fine with that.  I just don't want to have to jump through hoops if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between AS 2.0 and AS 3.0 is the depth management. In AS 2.0 you could use any depth you wanted. However, with AS 3.0 you can not (leave any depth unused/empty).

There are still several methods that allow you to change depth, swap depths etc. so you are free to use those.

Comment: But it's all relative to other display objects in 3.0.  What I used to accomplish in AS2.0 was defining, absolutely, the depth of the clip.  
I've been mulling over ideas in my head, and I think it's come to this:
every time my object changes its y, I could use getChildIndex to find its index, then check its y against the next highest (or lowest) index to see if they should swap?  That may accomplish what I need, but I guess I don't know my AS3.0 well enough to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really answer my question, since the question is a bit more specific than the concepts of depth/index management.  I at least _tried_ to do my homework, whether it was sufficient or not.